# Double simulation time to achieve 0.5 speed effect (slow motion)

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have a rigid body simulation set up, but I would like to double the simulation time; each frame in the last simulation, should last 2 frames now. I keep the same frames per second, to achieve the 0.5 speed effect (so actually scale time by 2. Does someone know how to do that? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the speed setting under Rigid Body World in the Scene settings.
[image]

Comment: Finally! The answer I've been looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Go to animation then go to dope sheet summary and press A, make that the diamonds become orange then S and press 2, use G to move the diamonds to the time you expect.

If you have no diamonds put animation and go the panel with the cube and put the start time<(frame), press I, select locrot, then there will appear diamonds, same to the next frame[image]

Comment: Thanks, but if I understand correctly this will only work if keyframes are used, right?

Comment: yup, but as you can see is easy

Answer (score 0):

Yo guys, I am late and the post is dead, but for you people using Blender 2.8+, there should be in the flip options the **[Time Scale]** slider, use that.

Comment: sorry but you are thinking of fluids. This question is asking about ridged body